# Django views does not exist or could not import

Tags: python, django, view, import

This morning i have been working on my project. I finished what i was doing and i pushed new code to git.

Now, i went to run my project to start working on it and index view does not run!

```
Could not import ism.views.index. View does not exist in module ism.views.
```

This view ran without any kind of problem. All the project ran.

There is something more incredible. i tried and checked other views after main view (ism.views.index) failed and all of them worked, but not now! All the views ran correctly 10 seconds ago and now neither works. They spit the same error of main view.

I found searching around the Internet this related topic:

[It's magic the view does not exist for django but it worked 5 secondes before and it still exist](http://python.6.n6.nabble.com/It-s-magic-the-view-does-not-exist-for-django-but-it-worked-5-secondes-before-and-it-still-exist-td4695300.html)

But i have tried to remove original file (views.py in ism app) and to write it again, and the problem persist. The same with all the rest views.py.

Anyone knows something about this issue?

Thanks =)

Comment: Do you have an `__init__.py` in your views directory? Try deleting all of the .pyc files for magical import problems.. `run git log <filename> ` to see all recent changes and review exactly what you changed in the related module.. Restart the server...  GL

Comment: did you add it in the installed_app list ?

Comment: I have removed all the .pyc files and it didn't work. Git doesn't give me any clue. Apps are added to installed_app too.

Something else? :(

Answer (score 58):

Try doing a

```
    python ./manage.py shell
```

and then importing the view that is giving you the problem. That might end up giving you more useful debugging information.

```
> from ism.views import index
```

Comment: Thanks!  Turns out one of the modules I was importing had an error in it.  I don't know why it wouldn't show the error, instead of saying it couldn't find the view.

Comment: You've won the internet - I just spent many hours trying to sniff out an error without an error message and you likely saved me many more.  Hats off.

Comment: Same problem here. Error was in a custom method of a script that I called in views.py. Django error msg is misleading.

Comment: I had an indentation error causing this. Thanks so much- would not have discovered otherwise since no error was being thrown.

Comment: The evilness of catching ImportError exceptions. Django does that throughout.

Comment: This does not worked for me. When i tried to run `./manage.py shell` I took the same error again.

Comment: wow, those error messages are really misleading :( thanks! saved me potentially hours of time

Comment: How do you load the view into the shell as outlined above?

Comment: @captainill `python ./manage.py shell` [new command:] `from your_module.your_view import your_view_function`

Answer (score 7):

It happened to me, eventually the problem was I had a syntax error in one of the forms in forms.py,
and I imported this form into my views.py file.
Django error message still pointed me to view does not exist error

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error for the same reason.  Typo in another file that was imported by the one reported in the error.  Revealed by importing manually into the shell.

Thanks kdazzle!

--Fred Stluka

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem by opening the view file in vim and saving without any change.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem.

My shell was not working too.

I saw the link that Jimenez posted, and at the end of  discussion the guy solved the problem saving the file using Vim.

I rewrited the file using Vim and it worked!

Try it if your was not solved yet!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I had no clues, importing the module in the shell was not helpful at all: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'views'`.
But I noticed that if I imported a specific module (that is imported in the views.py) before importing views, it worked.

I finally figured that the imported module also imported `views.py`, so it failed as each file was importing the other. No explicit message anywhere though.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue because of cross view import between two files.

I've resolve it by moving import inside of each method.