# Does adding a class to models.py ever cause "view does not exist" error?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, rating

I was trying to implement a rating system that receives the information that a user submits. 
But I was just wondering if it's possible to have two classes in one models file and get `Could not import myapp.comments.views.stars. View does not exist in module myapp.comments.views.`

In my models file, I have

```
class CommentWithRating(Comment):
    rating = models.IntegerField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.content_object.rating.add(score=self.rating, user=self.user, ip_address=self.ip_address)
        super(CommentWithRating, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Rating(models.Model):
    first_name = models.charField(maxlength=30)
    last_name = models.charField(maxlength=30)
    department = models.charField(maxlength=30)
    comment = models.charField(maxlength=10000)
    communi_rating = models.IntegerField()
    prepar_rating = models.IntegerField()
    interact_rating = models.IntegerField()
    help_rating = models.IntegerField()
```

By the way, stars is a html file. Any ideas?

This is my views,

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from models import CommentWithRating
def stars(request):
    return render(request, 'star.html', {'score': ''})
```

My error message is simply,

> Could not import myapp.comments.views.stars. View does not exist in module 
>   myapp.comments.views.

My traceback is,

> Environment:
>   Request Method: GET
>
> Django Version: 1.4
>
> Python Version: 2.7.2
>
> Installed Applications:
>
> ('django.contrib.auth',
>   'django.contrib.contenttypes',
>   'django.contrib.sessions',
>   'django.contrib.sites',
>   'django.contrib.messages',
>   'django.contrib.staticfiles',
>   'registration',
>   'django.contrib.admin',
>   'djangoratings')
>   Installed Middleware:
>   ('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
>   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')
>
> Traceback:
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
>    101.                             request.path_info)
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
>    300.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
>    209.             return ResolverMatch(self.callback, args, kwargs, self.name)
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in callback
>    216.         self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in wrapper
>    27.         result = func(*args)
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in get_callable
>    101.                     (lookup_view, mod_name))
>
> Exception Type: ViewDoesNotExist at /rating/
>   Exception Value: Could not import myapp.comments.views.stars. View does not exist in module >myapp.comments.views.`

Comment: Also add the content of your `myapp/comments/views.py` file please.

Comment: Do you have an __init__.py file in the comments folder?

Comment: Yea I do. Is that causing the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, that's definitely possible.

Try doing a

```
python ./manage.py shell
```

and then importing the model or view that is giving you the problem. That might end up giving you more useful debugging information.

(from [Django views does not exist or could not import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593194/django-views-does-not-exist-or-could-not-import))